# Drupal - General means for finding templates?

Tags: drupal, templates, themes

Given that I have a URL to a page and I can see the content on it as a user, is there a simple way to find out what template files are producing the page? Ideally I would like to know three things:

1. The current template file(s) being used
2. The filename(s) I can create in the local folder to customize them
3. What variables are available to these file(s)

I just want to know what the general procedure is for finding this information out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module includes a theme developer function that'll let you click anywhere in the page and determine what templates, theme functions, etc. are used (or can be used) to generate an element.

[image]

You can use PHP's `get_defined_vars()` function to get the variables available in a particular template or function.

Comment: Worth noting that this is now a separate devel_themer module, and not included in devel: http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer